# Как передать параметры сортировки из чексбоксов на сервер Django Ajax

Tags: python, массивы, django, json, ajax

Имеется форма с 3мя chackbox (к примеру).
Необходимо, чтобы при нажатии на любой (или несколько) из них происходила фильтрация данных на сервере Django.
Например, нажимаем 'Волгоград' и 'Урюпинск' выводятся художники из этих городов.
Код перестает работать при добавлении метода ajax.
Пулучается, по-моему тут 2 проблемы: работа метода Ajax и передача параметров на сервер Django.

Буду благодарна за любые дельные советы)

html (фрагмент)

```
<form class="myform">
   <input type="checkbox" name="city" value="Волгоград">Волгоград
   <input type="checkbox" name="city" value="Жирновск">Жирновск
   <input type="checkbox" name="city" value="Урюпинск">Урюпинск
</form>
```

JS (фрагмент)

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox][name=city]");
let res = [];

checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    res = Array.from(checkboxes).filter(i => i.checked).map(i => i.value);
    json_res = JSON.stringify(res);
    console.log(json_res);

    var csrftoken = $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();

     $.ajax(
    {
        type:"POST",
        url: "{% url 'AptPersons' %}",
        headers:{
        "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
        },
        cache: true,
        data: json_res,
        dataType : "json",
        success: function(response){
                showHtml(response);
        },
        error: function(response){
            $("#alert").text('Не работает');
        },
     })

  })
});
```

views.py (фрагмент)

```
@csrf_protect
def Apt_PerView(request):

    artPerson = sorted(ArtPerson.objects.all().order_by('name'), key=lambda x: random.random())

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['action'] == 'sort_up':
            artPerson = ArtPerson.objects.order_by('-name').values() #РАБОТАЕТ
        elif request.POST['action'] == 'sort_down':
            artPerson = ArtPerson.objects.order_by('name').values() #РАБОТАЕТ
        elif request.POST.getlist('arr[]') == ['Волгоград', 'Жирновск']:
            artPerson = ArtPerson.objects.filter(city="Волгоград").values() | ArtPerson.objects.filter(city="Жирновск").values() #НЕ РАБОТАЕТ
        elif request.POST.getlist['arr[]'] == ['Урюпинск']:
            artPerson = ArtPerson.objects.filter(city="Урюпинск").values() #НЕ РАБОТАЕТ
        # И так далее, всего 8 вариантов
        names = []
        cities = []
        slugs = []
        statuses = []
        image_artpersons=[]
        for d in artPerson:
            names.append(d['name'])
            cities.append(d['city'])
            slugs.append(d['slug_ap'])
            statuses.append(d['status'])
            image_artpersons.append(d['image_artperson'])
        json_data = {
            "names": names,
            "cities": cities,
            "slugs": slugs,
            "statuses": statuses,
            "image_artpersons": image_artpersons
        }
        return JsonResponse(json_data)
    else:
        return render(request, 'NewApp/Apt_Per.html', {'map_ArtPerson': artPerson})
```

Answer (score 0):

Первое, что вам нужно знать, это то, что при использовании ajax вы не должно использовать формы. Обычно на форму вешается `button type='submit'`, при нажатии на который страница будет **обновлена**. Использование ajax позволяет делать асинхронные **http get/post** запросы га сервер **не перезагружая** страницу.

Сначала вам нужно каждому `input` дать уникальный аттрибут `id`, для вашего кода будет примерно вот так:

```
<form class="myform">
   <input type="checkbox" id="id-volg" name="city" value="Волгоград">Волгоград
   <input type="checkbox" id="id-jirn" name="city" value="Жирновск">Жирновск
   <input type="checkbox" id="id-uup" name="city" value="Урюпинск">Урюпинск
</form>
```

Далее используем стандартную схему ajax запроса:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/your/url/point',
    method: 'post',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        field1: $('#id-volg').is(':checked'),
        field2: $('#id-jirn').is(':checked'),
        field3: $('#id-uup').is(':checked'),
    }),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: (response) => {
        // Do smth if success response (200, 201 e.t.c) 
    },
    error: (response) => {
        // Do smth if error response (400, 401, 403, 404, 50X e.t.c)
    }
})
```

Подставьте просто адрес ендпоинта и всё

**UPD:**
По поводу вопроса в комментариях. Вам стоит учесть две вещи.

Первое - структура data для отправки на сервер должна соответствовать модели на сервере. Ну как, ajax отправляет json объект, который может быть автоматически быть десереализирован фреймворком, либо в ручную вами путём вызова соответствующих методов. Т.е.все field1/2/3 должны иметь такие самые названия, как вы ожидаете получить их на сервере

Второе - изучите jQuery. В этой библиотеке есть очень много различных функций для выборки и работы с DOM структурой, что поможет вам получать такие значения без обращения на форум. Если вам нужно получить в результате что-то типа `{"field1":'Волгоград',"field2":'Жирновск',"field3":'Урюпинск'}`, вы можете использовать такую структуру для `data`:

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    field1: $('#id-volg').val(),
    field2: $('#id-jirn').val(),
    field3: $('#id-uup').val(),
})
```

Тут мы использовали метод `.val()`, который возвращает значения аттрибуты `value`. Так же вы можете использовать метод `.attr('attr-name')` подставив вместо `attr-name` название аттрибута, значения которого вы хотите получить

И напоследок, использования уникальных id это обычная практика для js и его библиотек, так что если не привыкли это делать, привыкайте) Привыкайте для все интеракивных элементов (*button, input, div для вывода ошибок (если работаете с Bootstrap), названия который могут меняться (label)*)

Comment: Спасибо, за ваш ответ. С id хорошая идея. Но, согласно вашему коду, отправляемые данные имеют вид {"field1":false,"field2":true,"field3":false} , а мне нужно к примеру {"field1":'Волгоград',"field2":'Жирновск',"field3":'Урюпинск'}.   В общем чтобы были названия отмеченных городов.

Comment: @Светлана , это пример того, как вам нужно отправлять данные. Я сейчас обновлю ответ и дополню его теорией по поводу вашего вопроса

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутое объяснение! Про отправку данных всё понятно. У меня так же как и у вас формировался json объект в виде json строки вида ['Волгоград', 'Жирновск', 'Урюпинск'] (если все чексбоксы помечены). Это первая часть вопроса. Но имеется и 2я часть вопроса ( не про JQuery) а про сортировку на стороне сервера с параметрами взятыми из чексбокса.

Comment: @Светлана, я не разбираюсь в Python и в Django тем более) Как обычных обитатель форума я дал ответ на вопрос с точки зрения понимая и подхода к решению задачи. Сортировка строк на сервере это уже более "низкий" уровень, который вы можете просто загуглить. Сортировки относятся к разделу именно программирования, а не языка программирования. По этому тут без обучения никак. Главное, что бы вы абсолютно правильно меня поняли, что я имею ввиду

Comment: @Светлана, если мой ответ помог вам, отметьте, пожалуйста, решением